# Looping origin and destination coordinates in R

Tags: r, loops, coordinates

I am looking to calculate the great circle distance between a set of longitude and latitude using the `distCosine` function available from `library(geosphere)`

the structure would follow

```
distCosine(c(Longo,Lato),c(Longd,Latd))
```

for each individual line,an example of the first two rows is shown below

```
      Longo     Lato    Longd     Latd
1 -2.098389 57.14816 4.965820 52.34876
2 -2.098389 57.14816 5.723877 58.96700
```

The value for the 1st line should be 700303.8

**How Do I Loop the Function To Then Calculate The 2nd Line?**

Ideally in addition to this is there a way to output these distance values

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
distCosine(as.matrix(df[,1:2]), as.matrix(df[,3:4]))
#[1] 700303.9 502835.0
```

This also seems to work though, it is not clear from `?distCosine`

```
distCosine(df[,1:2], df[,3:4])
#[1] 700303.9 502835.0
```

From `?distCosine`

> distCosine(p1, p2, r=6378137)
>
> p1: longitude/latitude of point(s). Can be a vector of two
>             numbers, a matrix of 2 columns (first one is longitude,
>             second is latitude) or a SpatialPoints* object
>
> p2: as above

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Longo = c(-2.098389, -2.098389), Lato = c(57.14816, 
57.14816), Longd = c(4.96582, 5.723877), Latd = c(52.34876, 58.967
)), .Names = c("Longo", "Lato", "Longd", "Latd"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 
 c("1", "2"))
```